# 'Wrong number of arguments' error in RUBY

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to build custom string based on data from my class **Map**.

```
class Map
  def initialize
    @data = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, 0) }
  end

  def [](x, y)
    @data[x][y]
  end

  def []=(x, y, value)
    @data[x][y] = value
  end
end
```

This is how I try to build a string:

```
def build_map_str(map)
  str = ' '
  (0..2).each do |i|
    (0..2).each do |j|
      str += case map[i][j]
             when 0
               "◻️ "
             when 1
               "❎ "
             when 2
               "️ "
             end
      str += '| ' if i != 2
    end
    str += "\n"
  end
end
```

And this is how I call this func:

```
map = Map.new
str = build_map_str(map)
```

But I am getting **in `[]': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)**. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your operator

```
  def [](x, y)
    @data[x][y]
  end
```

Your map's elements should be accessed via `map[i,j]` instead of `map[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition for `Map#[]` takes two arguments, so when you call it in `build_map_str`, it should look like this:

```
str += case map[i, j]
```

The same will apply when you assign values:

```
map[0, 0] = 0
```